# Send Mail Laravel XAMPP SMTP

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, xampp, laravel-5.3

I want to send mails from my application.

I want them to get sent from a specific host (SMTP, entering data for a email adress), and send it to a specified mail adress (changes every time).
I found several threads and explanations/questions how to do this, but nothings seems to really fit what I need or it doesn't match to my version. For example I found this: https://medium.com/@hasangilak/laravel-xampp-sending-local-email-smtp-e2010704d6d4#.4u5p15z74

But already the first thing to do is different in my version.
I'm using Laravel 5.3 and XAMPP with PHP 7.0.4.
So now the question is:
What do I have to edit in XAMPP configs to make it working, What and where do I have to edit something in Laravel to make it working? (Only enter the configuration in the .env file?) And how can I send the mails then via SMTP, is there a easy way to do this in Laravel, or should i download a plugin or how can I do this then?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in mail function of PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Try that first, and post your errors here afterwards.